# Nginx proxy timeout while uploading big files

Tags: nginx, timeout, upload

I'm experiencing strange behaviour with Nginx. In my case Nginx acts as proxy to Jetty. Config below:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    client_header_timeout 3m;
    client_body_timeout 3m;
    send_timeout 3m;
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    server_name test.com www.test.com
    location / {
         auth_basic     "Restricted area";
         auth_basic_user_file   /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
         proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080;
         proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto http;
         proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
         gzip on;
    }
}
```

When uploading a file with size greater than 5M I'm getting a'Gateway timeout'. CPU usage is 0%. I've no idea what's wrong. It's not related to a network speed because I'm testing this locally.

If I skip a proxy and try to upload file to app server directly (i mean: on port 8080), everything works like a charm.

Any idea ?? Regards!

Comment: Application handles a files larger than 5M. The main issue is with GW timeouts. A request with files bigger than 5M never comes to application server.

Answer (score 9):

Probably nginx upstream timeout needs to be increased. Try adding below to your upstream conf.

```
proxy_connect_timeout       600;
proxy_send_timeout          600;
proxy_read_timeout          600;
send_timeout                600;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to change the limit at

```
 client_max_body_size 5M;
```

to something like

```
 client_max_body_size 10M;
```

Comment: OK. but app server can handle files larger than 1GB and return exception bla bla bla.